# Will a gold coin react with an aqueous magnesium nitrate?

Tags: redox

I really have no work to show, I don't even know how to approach answering this... so if someone can push me in the right direction, thanks.

But I did have the idea that it might have something to do with how gold isn't a strong reducing agent.

Comment: Who downvoted :( ... Whoever did, was it a bad question?

Comment: Why checking a gold coin with magnesium nitrate ? This compound has not too many applications, not too many uses, not too many interesting properties

Answer (score 1):

The most common solution known to react with gold is a 1:3 mixture of nitric acid and hydrochloric acid classically known as "Aqua Regia." As such, it is unlikely that magnesium nitrate alone will react with gold as it is very stable.

Comment: OK. That makes sense... Does gold's stability correlate to its oxidizing abilities?

Comment: They are synonymous; as you stated earlier, gold is a bad reducing agent, meaning it is not easily oxidized, in a metallurgical sense, this means it is a very stable metal.